# Sorting the list of subnets as Integers ascending

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

I have a list of subnets for eg.

```
180.151.96.0/22
180.151.240.0/21
119.82.112.0/22
203.122.29.0/24
203.122.48.0/22
119.82.92.0/24
180.151.108.0/23
119.82.124.0/24
119.82.89.0/24
180.151.17.0/24
119.82.85.0/24
203.92.59.0/24
125.63.90.0/24
180.151.2.0/24
125.63.126.0/24
```

The output of these after using `sort -n` or `sort -g` is

```
119.82.112.0/22
119.82.124.0/24
119.82.85.0/24
119.82.89.0/24
119.82.92.0/24
125.63.126.0/24
125.63.90.0/24
180.151.108.0/23
180.151.17.0/24
180.151.2.0/24
180.151.240.0/21
180.151.96.0/22
203.122.29.0/24
203.122.48.0/22
203.92.59.0/24
```

I need the output as

```
119.82.85.0/24
119.82.89.0/24
119.82.92.0/24
119.82.112.0/22
119.82.124.0/24
125.63.90.0/24
125.63.126.0/24
180.151.2.0/24
180.151.17.0/24
180.151.96.0/22
180.151.108.0/23
180.151.240.0/21
203.92.59.0/24
203.122.29.0/24
203.122.48.0/22
```

Such output is only possible using Notepad++ feature 'Sort Lines as Integers Ascending'

Can someone please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU tools, use `sort -V` for a "natural sort".

Comment: Thanks.. It worked